# How to get Outgoing call number with date and time?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-broadcastreceiver

I am getting Incoming call Details(`Number,Name,Date`). But How to get outgoing call details. I have written a code for outgoing calls details but it throws `NullPointerException`. Below is my `MyCallReceiver`.java file and manifest file

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    this.context = context;



    if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

        String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

        Toast.makeText(context, "Call From : " + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        doToast(getContactName(context, incomingNumber) + " " + incomingNumber);
        String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        doToast(currentDateTimeString +" "+incomingNumber);


    } else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE) || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "DETECTED CALL HANG UP EVENT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        String outgoingNumber=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        Toast.makeText(context,"Calling To :"+outgoingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
 }
```

Comment: where is the manifest?

Comment: <receiver android:name=".MyCallReceiver" ><intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" /> <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
    </intent-filter></receiver><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    String state=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if(state==null)
    {
        //Outgoing call
        String number=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        Log.i("tag","Outgoing number : "+number);
    }
    else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
    {
        //Incoming call
        String number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        Log.i("tag","Incoming number : "+number);
    }
}
```

Comment: bro...everything is ok but, what about time?? and date ???, even im also looking for same thing. Im getting outgoing call number but i need exact outgoing call time.Help me out!!!

Answer (score 1):

First of all intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER) gives you outgoing number while phone state is idle and turns to "null" while phone status changes to OFF_HOOK.

The easiest way was to save the number before another onRecive happens.

Comment: I have used String outgoingNumber=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER); in my else if part but i am getting error

Comment: HariRam can you tell me where should i update my code to get outgoing call number

Comment: Im not sure, remove the off_hook condition. you might get the phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Creating separate listeners for different events (ie. incoming vs outgoing calls) might make your life easier. For outgoing calls, instead checking for state of TelephonyManager, you might want to create an `IntentFilter`.

```
IntentFilter filterCalls = new IntentFilter();
filterCalls.addAction(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
MyCallReceiver myCallReceiver = new MyCallReceiver();
registerReceiver(myCallReceiver, filterCalls);
```

Then in your `onReceive` you can simply have:

```
 String outgoingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER)
```

and be sure that it will work.